# Using a hook in react to change boolean and get a callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm trying to use a hook in React. The hook should give me a boolean and a callback. When the callback gets called the boolean should change value.
When I try to retrieve the value and the callback I get an error.

> Property `isEnabled` does not exist on type `(boolean | (() => void))[]`. On the line `const {isEnabled, toggleCallback} = useToggle()`;

What am I doing wrong?

```
function toggleCallback(toggleCallback: () => void) {
    toggleCallback();
}

export default function FakePage(props: any) {
    const {isEnabled, toggleCallback} = useToggle();
    return (
        <div>
            <ComponentOne isEnabled={isEnabled}/>
            <button onClick={() => testToggle(toggleCallback)}>Test</button>
        </div>
    );
}

// hook
export default function useToggle() {
    let isEnabled: boolean = true;
    const toggleCallback= useCallback(() => {
        isEnabled = !isEnabled;
    }, [isEnabled]);
    return [isEnabled, toggleCallback];
}
```

Comment: You are returning array from the hook but you destruct it as an object. either remove square brackets from callbacks and add curly brackets or change curly brackets in components to square brackets

Comment: It is worth noting that you should use useState() for isEnabled inside your hook. Also, you probably don't need to useCallback because it will work the same for when isEnabled is true and false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for the error and types, currently **you are returning a list** which contains `boolean` types and functions of type `() => void`, where you **want to return a tuple**.

```
// Return from custom hook
return [isEnabled, toggleCallback];

// use it like so, and not as object { isEnabled,setIsEnbaled }
const [isEnabled,setIsEnbaled] = useToggle();
```

Fix the return types with:

```
return [isEnabled, toggleCallback] as const;
```

Or specify the return type:

```
type HookProps = (initialState: boolean) => [boolean, () => void];
const useToggle: HookProps = (initialState) => {...}
```

As for the hook implementation, it should look in JS like so, as variables are not connected to state, using `toggleCallback` in your example won't trigger a render.

```
function useToggle(initialValue = true) {
  const [isEnabled, toggle] = useReducer((p) => !p, true);
  return [isEnabled, toggle];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

how to create custom hook :

```
export default function FakePage(props: any) {
    const {isEnabled, toggleCallback} = useToggle();
    return (
        <div>
            <ComponentOne isEnabled={isEnabled}/>
            <button onClick={toggleCallback}>Test</button>
        </div>
    );
}

// hook
export default function useToggle() {
    const [isEnabled,setIsEnabled] = useState(true)
    const toggleCallback= () => {
       setIsEnabled(current=>!current);
    };// no need to useCallback
    return {isEnabled, toggleCallback};
}

// and if you want to pass default value 

   export default function useToggle(default) {
        const [isEnabled,setIsEnabled] = useState(default)
        const toggleCallback= () => {
           setIsEnabled(current=>!current);
        };// no need to useCallback
        return {isEnabled, toggleCallback};
    }
// usage 
const {isEnabled, toggleCallback} = useToggle(false);
```

Comment: You should add an explanation, saying "no need to useCallback" ain't teaching/explaining much